# Adwords Script Exceeded maximum execution time

Tags: google-ads-api

I have a lot of inc active accounts and this is causing my ad words script to timeout. Is there any suggestions on how to exclude results that have no historical data. Currently the code stops running at 30 minutes I could not see a time limiter in the code. If anyone has experienced the same issue or has knowledge on how to prevent this error would really appreciate your help. Alternatively I can go through my adwords account and delete 100 inactive accounts. If there is no way to skip over the inactive accounts I am going to write a script to remove inactive accounts.

```
// Copyright 2017, Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

/**
 * @name MCC Account Anomaly Detector
 *
 * @fileoverview The MCC Account Anomaly Detector alerts the advertiser whenever
 * one or more accounts in a group of advertiser accounts under an MCC account
 * is suddenly behaving too differently from what's historically observed. See
 * https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/solutions/mccapp-account-anomaly-detector
 * for more details.
 *
 * @author AdWords Scripts Team [adwords-scripts@googlegroups.com]
 *
 * @version 1.4
 *
 * @changelog
 * - version 1.4
 *   - Added conversions to tracked statistics.
 * - version 1.3.2
 *   - Added validation for external spreadsheet setup.
 * - version 1.3.1
 *   - Improvements to time zone handling.
 * - version 1.3
 *   - Cleanup the script a bit for easier debugging and maintenance.
 * - version 1.2
 *   - Added AdWords API report version.
 * - version 1.1
 *   - Fix the script to work in accounts where there is no stats.
 * - version 1.0
 *   - Released initial version.
 */

var SPREADSHEET_URL = 'YOUR_SPREADSHEET_URL';

var CONFIG = {
  // Uncomment below to include an account label filter
  // ACCOUNT_LABEL: 'High Spend Accounts'
};

var CONST = {
  FIRST_DATA_ROW: 12,
  FIRST_DATA_COLUMN: 2,
  MCC_CHILD_ACCOUNT_LIMIT: 50,
  TOTAL_DATA_COLUMNS: 9
};

var STATS = {
  'NumOfColumns': 4,
  'Impressions':
      {'Column': 3, 'Color': 'red', 'AlertRange': 'impressions_alert'},
  'Clicks': {'Column': 4, 'Color': 'orange', 'AlertRange': 'clicks_alert'},
  'Conversions':
      {'Column': 5, 'Color': 'dark yellow 2', 'AlertRange': 'conversions_alert'},
  'Cost': {'Column': 6, 'Color': 'yellow', 'AlertRange': 'cost_alert'}
};

var DAYS = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday',
            'Saturday', 'Sunday'];

/**
 * Configuration to be used for running reports.
 */
var REPORTING_OPTIONS = {
  // Comment out the following line to default to the latest reporting version.
  apiVersion: 'v201705'
};

function main() {
  var account;
  var alertText = [];

  Logger.log('Using spreadsheet - %s.', SPREADSHEET_URL);
  var spreadsheet = validateAndGetSpreadsheet(SPREADSHEET_URL);
  spreadsheet.setSpreadsheetTimeZone(AdWordsApp.currentAccount().getTimeZone());

  var dataRow = CONST.FIRST_DATA_ROW;

  SheetUtil.setupData(spreadsheet);

  Logger.log('MCC account: ' + mccManager.mccAccount().getCustomerId());
  while (account = mccManager.next()) {
    Logger.log('Processing account ' + account.getCustomerId());
    alertText.push(processAccount(account, spreadsheet, dataRow));
    dataRow++;
  }

  sendEmail(mccManager.mccAccount(), alertText, spreadsheet);
}

/**
 * For each of Impressions, Clicks, Conversions, and Cost, check to see if the
 * values are out of range. If they are, and no alert has been set in the
 * spreadsheet, then 1) Add text to the email, and 2) Add coloring to the cells
 * corresponding to the statistic.
 *
 * @return {string} the next piece of the alert text to include in the email.
 */
function processAccount(account, spreadsheet, startingRow) {
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

  var thresholds = SheetUtil.thresholds();
  var today = AdWordsApp.report(SheetUtil.getTodayQuery(), REPORTING_OPTIONS);
  var past = AdWordsApp.report(SheetUtil.getPastQuery(), REPORTING_OPTIONS);

  var hours = SheetUtil.hourOfDay();
  var todayStats = accumulateRows(today.rows(), hours, 1); // just one week
  var pastStats = accumulateRows(past.rows(), hours, SheetUtil.weeksToAvg());

  var alertText = ['Account ' + account.getCustomerId()];
  var validWhite = ['', 'white', '#ffffff']; // these all count as white

  // Colors cells that need alerting, and adds text to the alert email body.
  function generateAlert(field, emailAlertText) {
    // There are 2 cells to check, for Today's value and Past value
    var bgRange = [
      sheet.getRange(startingRow, STATS[field].Column, 1, 1),
      sheet.getRange(startingRow, STATS[field].Column + STATS.NumOfColumns,
        1, 1)
    ];
    var bg = [bgRange[0].getBackground(), bgRange[1].getBackground()];

    // If both backgrounds are white, change background Colors
    // and update most recent alert time.
    if ((-1 != validWhite.indexOf(bg[0])) &&
        (-1 != validWhite.indexOf(bg[1]))) {
      bgRange[0].setBackground([[STATS[field]['Color']]]);
      bgRange[1].setBackground([[STATS[field]['Color']]]);

      spreadsheet.getRangeByName(STATS[field]['AlertRange']).
        setValue('Alert at ' + hours + ':00');
      alertText.push(emailAlertText);
    }
  }

  if (thresholds.Impressions &&
      todayStats.Impressions < pastStats.Impressions * thresholds.Impressions) {
    generateAlert('Impressions',
                  '    Impressions are too low: ' + todayStats.Impressions +
                  ' Impressions by ' + hours + ':00, expecting at least ' +
                  parseInt(pastStats.Impressions * thresholds.Impressions));
  }

  if (thresholds.Clicks &&
      todayStats.Clicks < (pastStats.Clicks * thresholds.Clicks).toFixed(1)) {
    generateAlert('Clicks',
                  '    Clicks are too low: ' + todayStats.Clicks +
                  ' Clicks by ' + hours + ':00, expecting at least ' +
                  (pastStats.Clicks * thresholds.Clicks).toFixed(1));
  }

  if (thresholds.Conversions &&
      todayStats.Conversions <
          (pastStats.Conversions * thresholds.Conversions).toFixed(1)) {
    generateAlert(
        'Conversions',
        '    Conversions are too low: ' + todayStats.Conversions +
            ' Conversions by ' + hours + ':00, expecting at least ' +
            (pastStats.Conversions * thresholds.Conversions).toFixed(1));
  }

  if (thresholds.Cost &&
      todayStats.Cost > (pastStats.Cost * thresholds.Cost).toFixed(2)) {
    generateAlert(
        'Cost',
        '    Cost is too high: ' + todayStats.Cost + ' ' +
            account.getCurrencyCode() + ' by ' + hours +
            ':00, expecting at most ' +
            (pastStats.Cost * thresholds.Cost).toFixed(2));
  }

  // If no alerts were triggered, we will have only the heading text. Remove it.
  if (alertText.length == 1) {
    alertText = [];
  }

  var dataRows = [[
    account.getCustomerId(), todayStats.Impressions, todayStats.Clicks,
    todayStats.Conversions, todayStats.Cost, pastStats.Impressions.toFixed(0),
    pastStats.Clicks.toFixed(1), pastStats.Conversions.toFixed(1),
    pastStats.Cost.toFixed(2)
  ]];

  sheet.getRange(startingRow, CONST.FIRST_DATA_COLUMN,
    1, CONST.TOTAL_DATA_COLUMNS).setValues(dataRows);

  return alertText;
}

var SheetUtil = (function() {
  var thresholds = {};
  var upToHour = 1; // default
  var weeks = 26; // default

  var todayQuery = '';
  var pastQuery = '';

  var setupData = function(spreadsheet) {
    Logger.log('Running setupData');
    spreadsheet.getRangeByName('date').setValue(new Date());
    spreadsheet.getRangeByName('account_id').setValue(
        mccManager.mccAccount().getCustomerId());

    var getThresholdFor = function(field) {
      thresholds[field] = parseField(spreadsheet.
          getRangeByName(field).getValue());
    };
    getThresholdFor('Impressions');
    getThresholdFor('Clicks');
    getThresholdFor('Conversions');
    getThresholdFor('Cost');

    var now = new Date();

    // Basic reporting statistics are usually available with no more than a 3-hour
    // delay.
    var upTo = new Date(now.getTime() - 3 * 3600 * 1000);
    upToHour = parseInt(getDateStringInTimeZone('h', upTo));

    spreadsheet.getRangeByName('timestamp').setValue(
        DAYS[getDateStringInTimeZone('u', now)] + ', ' + upToHour + ':00');

    if (upToHour == 1) {
      // First run of the day, clear existing alerts.
      spreadsheet.getRangeByName(STATS['Clicks']['AlertRange']).clearContent();
      spreadsheet.getRangeByName(STATS['Impressions']['AlertRange']).
          clearContent();
      spreadsheet.getRangeByName(STATS['Conversions']['AlertRange'])
          .clearContent();
      spreadsheet.getRangeByName(STATS['Cost']['AlertRange']).clearContent();

      // Reset background and font Colors for all data rows.
      var bg = [];
      var ft = [];
      var bg_single = [
        'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white', 'white',
        'white'
      ];
      var ft_single = [
        'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black',
        'black'
      ];

      // Construct a 50-row array of colors to set.
      for (var a = 0; a < CONST.MCC_CHILD_ACCOUNT_LIMIT; ++a) {
        bg.push(bg_single);
        ft.push(ft_single);
      }

      var dataRegion = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0].getRange(
        CONST.FIRST_DATA_ROW, CONST.FIRST_DATA_COLUMN,
        CONST.MCC_CHILD_ACCOUNT_LIMIT, CONST.TOTAL_DATA_COLUMNS);

      dataRegion.setBackgrounds(bg);
      dataRegion.setFontColors(ft);
    }

    var weeksStr = spreadsheet.getRangeByName('weeks').getValue();
    weeks = parseInt(weeksStr.substring(0, weeksStr.indexOf(' ')));

    var dateRangeToCheck = getDateStringInPast(0, upTo);
    var dateRangeToEnd = getDateStringInPast(1, upTo);
    var dateRangeToStart = getDateStringInPast(1 + weeks * 7, upTo);
    var fields = 'HourOfDay, DayOfWeek, Clicks, Impressions, Conversions, Cost';

    todayQuery = 'SELECT ' + fields +
        ' FROM ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING ' + dateRangeToCheck + ',' +
        dateRangeToCheck;
    pastQuery = 'SELECT ' + fields +
        ' FROM ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT WHERE DayOfWeek=' +
        DAYS[getDateStringInTimeZone('u', now)].toUpperCase() +
        ' DURING ' + dateRangeToStart + ',' + dateRangeToEnd;
  };

  var getThresholds = function() { return thresholds; };
  var getHourOfDay = function() { return upToHour; };
  var getWeeksToAvg = function() { return weeks; };
  var getPastQuery = function() { return pastQuery; };
  var getTodayQuery = function() { return todayQuery; };

  // The SheetUtil public interface.
  return {
    setupData: setupData,
    thresholds: getThresholds,
    hourOfDay: getHourOfDay,
    weeksToAvg: getWeeksToAvg,
    getPastQuery: getPastQuery,
    getTodayQuery: getTodayQuery
  };
})();

function sendEmail(account, alertTextArray, spreadsheet) {
  var bodyText = '';
  alertTextArray.forEach(function(alertText) {
    // When zero alerts, this is an empty array, which we don't want to add.
    if (alertText.length == 0) { return }
    bodyText += alertText.join('\n') + '\n\n';
  });
  bodyText = bodyText.trim();

  var email = spreadsheet.getRangeByName('email').getValue();
  if (bodyText.length > 0 && email && email.length > 0 &&
      email != 'foo@example.com') {
    Logger.log('Sending Email');
    MailApp.sendEmail(email,
        'AdWords Account ' + account.getCustomerId() + ' misbehaved.',
        'Your account ' + account.getCustomerId() +
        ' is not performing as expected today: \n\n' +
        bodyText + '\n\n' +
        'Log into AdWords and take a look: ' +
        'adwords.google.com\n\nAlerts dashboard: ' +
        SPREADSHEET_URL);
  }
  else if (bodyText.length == 0) {
    Logger.log('No alerts triggered. No email being sent.');
  }
}

function toFloat(value) {
  value = value.toString().replace(/,/g, '');
  return parseFloat(value);
}

function parseField(value) {
  if (value == 'No alert') {
    return null;
  } else {
    return toFloat(value);
  }
}

function accumulateRows(rows, hours, weeks) {
  var result = {Clicks: 0, Impressions: 0, Conversions: 0, Cost: 0};

  while (rows.hasNext()) {
    var row = rows.next();
    var hour = row['HourOfDay'];

    if (hour < hours) {
      result = addRow(row, result, 1 / weeks);
    }
  }

  return result;
}

function addRow(row, previous, coefficient) {
  if (!coefficient) {
    coefficient = 1;
  }
  if (!row) {
    row = {Clicks: 0, Impressions: 0, Conversions: 0, Cost: 0};
  }
  if (!previous) {
    previous = {Clicks: 0, Impressions: 0, Conversions: 0, Cost: 0};
  }
  return {
    Clicks: parseInt(row['Clicks']) * coefficient + previous.Clicks,
    Impressions:
        parseInt(row['Impressions']) * coefficient + previous.Impressions,
    Conversions:
        parseInt(row['Conversions']) * coefficient + previous.Conversions,
    Cost: toFloat(row['Cost']) * coefficient + previous.Cost
  };
}

function checkInRange(today, yesterday, coefficient, field) {
  var yesterdayValue = yesterday[field] * coefficient;
  if (today[field] > yesterdayValue * 2) {
    Logger.log('' + field + ' too much');
  } else if (today[field] < yesterdayValue / 2) {
    Logger.log('' + field + ' too little');
  }
}

/**
 * Produces a formatted string representing a date in the past of a given date.
 *
 * @param {number} numDays The number of days in the past.
 * @param {date} date A date object. Defaults to the current date.
 * @return {string} A formatted string in the past of the given date.
 */
function getDateStringInPast(numDays, date) {
  date = date || new Date();
  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var past = new Date(date.getTime() - numDays * MILLIS_PER_DAY);
  return getDateStringInTimeZone('yyyyMMdd', past);
}


/**
 * Produces a formatted string representing a given date in a given time zone.
 *
 * @param {string} format A format specifier for the string to be produced.
 * @param {date} date A date object. Defaults to the current date.
 * @param {string} timeZone A time zone. Defaults to the account's time zone.
 * @return {string} A formatted string of the given date in the given time zone.
 */
function getDateStringInTimeZone(format, date, timeZone) {
  date = date || new Date();
  timeZone = timeZone || AdWordsApp.currentAccount().getTimeZone();
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format);
}


/**
 * Module that deals with fetching and iterating through multiple accounts.
 *
 * @return {object} callable functions corresponding to the available
 * actions. Specifically, it currently supports next, current, mccAccount.
 */
var mccManager = (function() {
  var accountIterator;
  var mccAccount;
  var currentAccount;

  // Private one-time init function.
  var init = function() {
    var accountSelector = MccApp.accounts();

    // Use this to limit the accounts that are being selected in the report.
    if (CONFIG.ACCOUNT_LABEL) {
        accountSelector.withCondition("LabelNames CONTAINS '" +
            CONFIG.ACCOUNT_LABEL + "'");
    }

    accountSelector.withLimit(CONST.MCC_CHILD_ACCOUNT_LIMIT);
    accountIterator = accountSelector.get();

    mccAccount = AdWordsApp.currentAccount(); // save the mccAccount
    currentAccount = AdWordsApp.currentAccount();
  };

  /**
   * After calling this, AdWordsApp will have the next account selected.
   * If there are no more accounts to process, re-selects the original
   * MCC account.
   *
   * @return {AdWordsApp.Account} The account that has been selected.
   */
  var getNextAccount = function() {
    if (accountIterator.hasNext()) {
      currentAccount = accountIterator.next();
      MccApp.select(currentAccount);
      return currentAccount;
    }
    else {
      MccApp.select(mccAccount);
      return null;
    }

  };

  /**
   * Returns the currently selected account. This is cached for performance.
   *
   * @return {AdWords.Account} The currently selected account.
   */
  var getCurrentAccount = function() {
    return currentAccount;
  };

 /**
  * Returns the original MCC account.
  *
  * @return {AdWords.Account} The original account that was selected.
  */
  var getMccAccount = function() {
    return mccAccount;
  };

  // Set up internal variables; called only once, here.
  init();

  // Expose the external interface.
  return {
    next: getNextAccount,
    current: getCurrentAccount,
    mccAccount: getMccAccount
  };

})();

/**
 * Validates the provided spreadsheet URL and email address
 * to make sure that they're set up properly. Throws a descriptive error message
 * if validation fails.
 *
 * @param {string} spreadsheeturl The URL of the spreadsheet to open.
 * @return {Spreadsheet} The spreadsheet object itself, fetched from the URL.
 * @throws {Error} If the spreadsheet URL or email hasn't been set
 */
function validateAndGetSpreadsheet(spreadsheeturl) {
  if (spreadsheeturl == 'YOUR_SPREADSHEET_URL') {
    throw new Error('Please specify a valid Spreadsheet URL. You can find' +
        ' a link to a template in the associated guide for this script.');
  }
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheeturl);
  var email = spreadsheet.getRangeByName('email').getValue();
  if ('foo@example.com' == email) {
    throw new Error('Please either set a custom email address in the' +
        ' spreadsheet, or set the email field in the spreadsheet to blank' +
        ' to send no email.');
  }
  return spreadsheet;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  Take a look [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/limits).  The scripts time out after 30 mins unless they execute in parallel.